# my default route '/' ie Home does not adapt old class ie Normal in Navlink

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx

I am trying to work with NavLink and using its activeClassName prop it works for all routes but not for home route

**JSX CODE**

```
<ul>
   <NavLink to='/'  className="normal" activeClassName='active'>Home</NavLink>
   <NavLink to='/menu'   className="normal" activeClassName='active'>Menu</NavLink>
   <NavLink to='/about_us'  className="normal" activeClassName='active'>About</NavLink>
   <NavLink to='/contact_us'  className="normal" activeClassName='active'>Contact</NavLink>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.active {
color: red;
font-weight: 600;}
```

so when I route using the above links the Home route fails to change back to the default style

so when I click on contact home remains bold and when I click About contact changes its style but not home

> **Home** Menu About **Contact**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the attribute exact. The way you set it up it first matches `/` and then `/contact_us`. More info in [the react router docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/exact-bool).

Also consider using `li` as children for `ul`. As it is more semantic.